# How to change a model via a button?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a function on my website which allows a user to delete their listings. What I want to happen is for them to click on a button which says "delete listing", this is then followed up by a new page which asks them to "Confirm" they want to delete their listing. Once this button is clicked they should be re-directed to to the index page. I am having some problems with this as when they confirm they want to delete their listing it is not suppose to actually delete the listing it just changes a field in the listing to 'False'. All my current attempts have failed, how can I change a field in a model when somebody clicks a button? My best idea was to have the button link to another page which then changes the model however I thought this seemed like an inefficient way to do this.
Cheers

View -

```
@login_required(redirect_field_name='login')
def deletelistingconfirm(request, pk):

    post = JobListing.objects.get(pk=pk)
    print(post)

    if str(request.user) != str(post.user):
        return redirect("index")

    context_dict = {}

    return render(request, 'delete_listing_confirm.html', context_dict)
```

Comment: "All my current attempts have failed." Please show us some of them.

Comment: I have really just attempted a Java script solution which someone suggested in another stack overflow question however that was not really suited for my project. My code is currently just loading the page as I am trying to figure out ideas but I'll put that up anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is a SAP (Single Page Application). This will allow you to do all your changes in the database records without reloading the page but via ajax.
However, there will be more work as you will need an API for the SAP to work.
You might want to give django-rest-framework a shot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did a little bit of research and came to a similar conclusion. In the end I just created another page which ran the function but displayed no content and immediately redirected the user to another page.